# How can I fill "ğ" to the text without any corruption?

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8

I try to make a email signature generator using canvas. Because Turkish names include letters like "ğ" that does not exist in utf-8, when I fill the text to the canvas, it is corrupted, but when I click button twice, corruption is does not exist anymore. How can I fix this?

codes are here:

```js
$("#formButton").click(function() {
  var name = $("#formName").val();
  var title = $("#formTitle").val();

  Promise.all([
    document.fonts.load("700 32px Roboto"),
    document.fonts.load("300 20px Roboto"),
  ]).then(() => {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-top");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.font = "700 32px Roboto";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#1F5890";
    ctx.fillText(name, 15, 80);

    ctx.font = "300 20px Roboto";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#1F5890";
    ctx.fillText(title, 15, 105);
  });

  console.log(name, title);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;500;700&display=swap" />
<form>
  <input type="text" id="formName" value="Gündoğdu" />
  <input type="text" id="formTitle" value="Gündoğdu" />
  <input type="button" id="formButton" value="Click" />
</form>
<canvas id="canvas-top"></canvas>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: _"letters like "ğ" that does not exist in utf-8"_ - of course this letter can be encoded in UTF-8 ... this very site here uses UTF-8 character encoding, and you were able to post it here, weren't you?

Comment: `ğ` exists in utf-8:  it is `U+011F` (`c4 9f`)

Comment: The first image indicates that the font that you use does not support that letter. For the second image, it is not clear what is happening there.

Comment: Maybe the first use of this character triggers loading of a different font in the background, that contains instructions on how to render this glyph - but that is not finished the first time you paint onto the canvas, so it only works as desired the second time ...?

Comment: How can I load it for turkish characters?

Comment: How do you load/inlcude the font `Roboto` in your page?

Comment: <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;500;700&display=swap "
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

Comment: @mplungjan it does not work as expected, as the snipped does not use the same font. In the image you can see a fallback font being used, and the desired font, does not have that character available in the first run.

Comment: it does not help me

Comment: something help character to be available in the second run, if I find it, I can load it in promise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on you comment you load the font with this URL `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;500;700`

The important part here is that google fonts is delivering the font splitter into multiple files for different character sets, which are loaded on demand.

Drawing the text triggers the loading of the required file, but the drawing happens before that file was loaded.

That's why your letter does not appear correctly for the first draw but will be correct when you trigger the draw a second time.

One thing you could do is to utilize the `text` parameter of the [fonts.load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet/load) function, and pass the text you want to draw with that font:

```js
$("#formButton").click(function() {
  var name = $("#formName").val();
  var title = $("#formTitle").val();

  Promise.all([
    document.fonts.load("700 32px Roboto", name),

    document.fonts.load("300 20px Roboto", title),
  ]).then(() => {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-top");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.font = "700 32px Roboto";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#1F5890";
    ctx.fillText(name, 15, 80);

    ctx.font = "300 20px Roboto";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#1F5890";
    ctx.fillText(title, 15, 105);
  });

  console.log(name, title);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;500;700&display=swap" />
<form>
  <input type="text" id="formName" value="Gündoğdu" />
  <input type="text" id="formTitle" value="Gündoğdu" />
  <input type="button" id="formButton" value="Click" />
</form>
<canvas id="canvas-top"></canvas>
```

Comment: I thought based on my tests that the fonts did not start loading until the user had made some interaction with the page. See my deleted answer

Comment: @mplungjan I also did some similar tests. The strange thing is that if you set the font of the `input` to Robot it won't work either until you set the font size to something else than the default. Even so, the font looks correct for the input element.